# RSpec controller spec, how to set JSON body AND URL params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

```rb
body = { a: 1 }.to_json
params = { b: 2 }
post(:create, body: body, params: params, as: :json)
```

In the controller I have `params[:a]` but not `params[:b]`?

Maybe `body` is taking presidence since the parsed body becomes `params` in the controller, but in this case how do I also pass URL params?

If I remove `as: :json` I see the URL params in `params` but not the parsed JSON body as the MIME type is `text/html` not `text/json`.

The `body` is loaded from a fixture and must be sent as is because the body is signed, so it can't be merged with `params`, i.e. `params: JSON.parse(body).merge(params)`.

I can hack around this problem as such:

```rb
request.query_string = "b=2"
post(:create, body: body, params: params, as: :json)
```

In this case I get both the URL and body params in `params`, so it seems the Rails controller does the right thing when given both a JSON body and URL params.

Answer (score 0):

If we change the routes as such:

```rb
post '/foo?a=:a', to: 'foos#create'
```

we do end up with both the defined URL params and body params in `params`.